# Response Header Size in Grails Controller class

Tags: grails, response, httpresponse

Is it possible to find out the size of response header in Grails Controller groovy class ?

Comment: Are you looking at specific headers?

Comment: I want collective size of all headers in the response object.

Answer (score 0):

Can't test it out right now but something like this should work:

```
def headers = response.getHeaderNames()

def size
headers.each { header ->
    def headerValue = response.getHeader(header)
    // get the size of headerValue in whatever unit you're looking for and add it to
    // the size variable
}
```

Remember this is free hand since I don't have the setup to test it right now but grails response objects are just instances of [HttpServletResponse](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) so it should be pretty simple.

Comment: Actually, I want to know in my code that what is being carried by response object. Please help

Comment: I want debugging on response header

Comment: I tried this - log.info("--->>> : ${new GetMethod(request.getRequestURL().toString()).getResponseHeaders()}") But this gives empty array

Comment: I have googled that HttpExchange and HttpMethod classed have getResponseHeaders() method. But How can I use it properly ?

Comment: Before getting into your questions, do you need to know the size of the response headers within the code so you can do something with it...or do you need to know for reasons that you won't put into the code?

Comment: Actually, when response header size exceeds 8 KB, my tomcat is not able to handle it and throws exception. This happens on PROD. So I want to add logging on response header to check what is being carried by response object that makes it size so large.

Comment: Use fiddler http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ or some other http debugger. You can customize a request to send and it captures the response for you to view in different ways.